# I have to send 2 signals to send a message immidiately in IE and Firefox (SSE)

Tags: silverlight, signalr

I'm developing a signalr app having a silverlight client and my project structure is

- A web app having the server (hub)
- a wpf app having the wpf client (for the first client)
- a web app for the other web (silverlight) clients

The problem I'm having is that when I try to send a message to other clients in one of the web clients using Firefox or IE, I need to wait around 2 seconds. But if I send another signal or 2 signals in the same time, It works fine. I can assure that my signals are sent on time only if I send 2 messages.

Could this be because of the transport or sthg that I need to configure? Clients are working fine with Chrome.

Comment: no I'm not using Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Forcing the transport to Longpolling has solved my problem.

here is how I start the connection

```
        IClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport();
        await HubConnection.Start(transport);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, we have documented the issue on the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes)

Server sent events has known issues on Silverlight

Messages are delayed when using server sent events on silverlight. To force long polling use the following:

connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());